# Failing to manage a Public Ip

Tags: networking, ip

**Here is the scenario:**
I have asked my ISP to give me public IP, which I can connect to my laptop and access from other outside network. They gave me following

```
IP              : 103.51.2.198
subnet mask     : 255.255.255.248
default Gateway : 103.51.2.193
preferred dns   : 8.8.8.8
Alternate dns   : 8.8.4.4
```

I have connected PPPoE connection in my laptop (not in router) and set these values at TCP/IP V4. My internet connection is fine.

But If I ping from other network by this IP (`103.51.2.198`), request is timed out.

Than I checked `whatsmyrealip`. and the IP is (`103.51.2.102`). this IP is a public IP of my ISP provider. And they are trying to give me an IP from that IP.

My ISP providers are not expert in networking nor am I. They are also not sure how they can give me a public IP.

I am not sure about what are they trying to do. and how will they give me another IP from a public IP. It will be very helpful, If anyone can explain the problem. and give a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's called `public IP` not "realIP".

Anyways, the answer for your question is:

You cannot access your home computer because it is behind `NAT` so it is unreachable from the outside of your network.

Quick example on how `NAT` works:

> **Scenario:**
>
> Private IP: 192.168.0.10
>
> Public IP: 1.2.3.4
>
> You are connecting to webserver on IP: 5.5.5.5
>
> **What happens:**
>
> You send data to your router, telling it that you want something from
>   `5.5.5.5`, your router assigns you a random port, let's say `11111`,
>   sends the data with source IP `1.2.3.4` and port `11111`. Stuff
>   happens on the webserver and the data comes back. Router reads it and
>   remembers that everything going to `1.2.3.4:11111` belongs to
>   `192.168.0.10` so it sends you the data.

Here everything works because it's your computer the one starting the connection, otherwise, the webserver would never be able to connect to you.

Comment: Alex, I am directly connecting the PPPoE connection to my laptop. Should I connect it to my router and set the ip and others in the router? And than Forward the port?